# Center logo in web page (vertically & Horizontally)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a logo  (775 X 225)   that I would like to center (both vertically and horizontally) in a web page and then have a link "Enter", placed  underneath it

```
<html>
<head>
 <Title> My website </Title>
 <style type="text/css">
   //centerlogo CSS class here ?
 </style>
</head>
<body lang=EN-US>
<div class'centerlogo"> <span></span>
<img src="images/logo.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

what is the best way to do this so that it is centered both vertically and horizontally and works in all browsers?

Can someone show me the CSS class if its the best method - or javascript code if it is the best method?

I tried looking at a few examples on here, but couldn't get any of them to work with my image.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the logo is a known size, then you can position it absolutely with negative margins equal to half the width and height.

```
.centerlogo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 775px;
    height: 225px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -387px; //Half the width
    margin-top: -112px; //Half the height
}
```

This will remain in the exact center of the screen regardless of the size of the window.

Comment: Unless it's obvious, this element should have no non-`static` ancestor elements, otherwise it'll be centered in that ancestor. For example, this can't be nested in elements where any of those elements have the `position` style specified

Comment: I think you mean `position`? But yes, this will work provided `.centerlogo` is not nested in anything else that is positioned.

Comment: Sorry, yeah I meant `position`.

Comment: hmm, I must bedoing something wrong, cause its still in the top left of the page. how does the HTML portion look in relation to the class you provided?  Can you please re-edit your code to show me.

Comment: ahhh, I was missing the "=" and I had a single quote instead of a double quote - <div class'centerlogo">    it should have been - <div class="centerlogo">    but it still doesn't center it 100% vertically. Its closer to the bottom than the top

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it the `top` value might be a problem. You might need to set `top:25%;` or something like that... This is because the percentages are based on the window's width, an annoying property of CSS.

Comment: You could also try setting your body and html elements to 100% width and height: `body,html{ width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

Comment: Thank You, appreciate all the help!

Comment: @JakeSnake And you might notice that some browsers give the `body` and/or `html` a `margin` or `padding` that you might want to set to `0`

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this on the item you want centered.
Here is an example of the output: http://jsfiddle.net/FjLQY/1/

```
img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 128px; /* height of item */
    height: 128px; /* width of item */
}
```